# How do I install resource packs on minecraft 1.8.8?

Tags: minecraft

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop and Minecraft as well, but when I open the resource packs folder button, it opens it in Google Chrome... HELP!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will do that when I get home from school tomorow.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an odd problem.

Simply press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> keys on your keyboard, and type `nautilus ~/.minecraft/resourcepacks`. The ResourcePack folder should open right up.

Drag and drop your resource pack right in to the folder. You should be able to use them in-game from then on.

---

As for your problem with the file opening in Chrome, that sounds like Chrome taking over the folder control.

All you need to do is open a terminal and type `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

From there, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and type `directory`.

Change `google-chrome.desktop` to `nautilus.desktop` and reboot.

But Chrome wont provide you the rich features provided by Nautilus.

Comment: Which google-chrome.desktop do I change? I am seeing 7 of them

Comment: @TrevinRNightFire There should be a specific entry for directories. Change that one.